# Grouping values for a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Im new to mysql (coming from JS) and I would like to know how to group values for a column in a table (Like in JS you would make an array of strings)?
I have this code so far, which throws an error:

```
CREATE TABLE phone (
    type ('home', 'office', 'mobile')
 );
```

I need to have the name of the column as "type" and either one of those values - 'home', 'office' or 'mobile'.
Thanks!

Comment: Please look at [ENUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html).I think that is your need?

Comment: See the manual under data types - but equally (well, actually, better), consider storing allowable 'types' is a separate table, and then enacting a FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT

Comment: And, while not 'reserved', note that 'type' is acknowledged as a KEYWORD in MySQL, so perhaps best avoided as a table/column identifier.

Comment: @Strawberry For a small number of possible values wouldn't using enum be better than using foreign key?As far as I know the advantage of foreign key in this case would be a dynamic set of possible values?

Comment: @GirishSrivatsa We're rapidly moving in to opinion territory. For myself, I wouldn't use ENUM or SET data types. Working from home, I now have a home-office phone; an easy thing to incorporate into my schema, and impossible to incorporate into yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do, is define the column named `type` as `enum`. So the values of your column can only be one of the listed values  `('home', 'office', 'mobile')`.
Documentation for MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html
Documentation for MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/enum/

This code should work on both systems:

```
CREATE TABLE phone (
    type ENUM('home', 'office', 'mobile')
);
```